# opengl32.dll and Windows 10 update

Tags: opengl, windows-10

I'm in the process of debugging my application, which was working well with opengl on Windows 10.  The app is broken because of a seemingly missing opengl function.  The problem seems to have started when I installed the latest update for Windows 10.  I suspect that opengl32.dll is missing key functions for Windows.

Specifically, I always gained access to wglChoosePixelFormatARB by calling Windows wglGetProcAddress.  However, wglGetProcAddress now returns a null pointer for this function.

As a workaround, I tried to gain access to wglChoosePixelFormatARB by using the LoadLibrary of opengl32.dll and GetProcAddress.   The return value is still a null, and the GetLastError returns ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND.

To double-check the issue, I downloaded a dll export viewer tool from nirsoft.com.  I saw that wglChoosePixelFormatARB  is not listed in opengl32.dll, whereas the older function, wglChoosePixelFormat, is there.  The wglChoosePixelFormat function is a much older way to choose the format.  What is the logic behind distributing this opengl32 dll?

I read the following answer from Microsoft, but it doesn't seem that another update is available or that the answer will fix my problem:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/problems-with-opengl32dll/23c4b0e6-8742-412a-8a4e-2c6024cc78e1

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: "*I tried to gain access to wglChoosePixelFormatARB by using the LoadLibrary of opengl32.dll and GetProcAddress*" Yeah, that's *never* gonna work. `wglGetProcAddress` exists precisely *because* opengl32.dll does not expose such functions. The installed ICD driver does, and unless you go out and find that DLL (which is different for different vendors), you cannot use `GetProcAddress` to read OpenGL function pointers.

Comment: or use GLEW or any other OpenGL extension wrangler instead ...

Comment: It seems clearly a driver bug. `wglChoosePixelFormatARB `must be supported and queried with `wglGetProcAddress`or otherwise zillions of existing apps will fail.

Comment: wglGetProcAddress also returned a not found on that function.  I agree that it must be a driver bug, but I am told that there is no update for the graphic device under device manager.  Also, If GetProcAddress should not work on opengl32.dll why is it that it returns a proc address for wglChoosePixelFormat and NOT for wglChoosePixelFormatARB?
Is it possible to force a driver install?

Comment: A driver re-install is easy. You should be able to get the vendor-specific needed files (.exe or .msi). likely at your vendor web. The *Device Manager* is another route, looking at *unistall* and then *previous driver*. One more way: In "Configuration->Update" review the history and unistall some update.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  The most sensible solution - driver update - did not do the trick and my wglGetProcAddress still cannot find wglChoosePixelFormatARB.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Dell's Intel HD driver update from Nov 2017 is messing up OpenGL.  One way to solve the problem is to use Dell's older driver update.

This might be wrong; the older drive might not include the Intel security update. Choose your poison.

The working driver is here:

https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=40Y1J